# Jupyter Notebook Markdown not Showing in GitHub

Tags: github, jupyter-notebook

I am learning about markdown cells for Jupyter notebooks, and I've tried to create a simple, crimson title for one of my notebooks using the following code:

```
# <font color=crimson>Dataquest Guided Project 1:</font>
```

In the Jupyter notebook, this becomes a  crimson header when I run the cell, as expected and as outline here: http://datascience.ibm.com/blog/markdown-for-jupyter-notebooks-cheatsheet/.

When I upload the notebook to GitHub, everything else about my Jupyter notebook displays correctly except for the crimson header, which, although it has a header font, actually displays the words "# Dataquest Guided Project 1:".

Is something getting lost in translation? How can I fix this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the styling technique you are using to style the contents of the markdown cells....if you are using html tags to style the markdown cells, then those markdown cells wont be rendered on github . Instead you should use other styling techniques like # - for heading, * - for bold, ** - for italics etc. These styling techniques are interpreted by github and hence those markdown cells are visible when you upload the jupyter notebook on github.

Comment: The user posted an example of using markdown code to format the color of large printed text (size #).  This is the correct way to format code within a Jupyter markdown cell.  But the chosen color (crimson) within the tag needs to be enclosed within parenthesis.   While Jupyter might  provide a color associated with this tag, the color will not necessarily be crimson.  Github did not print the text in color due to the missing parenthesis.